# Локальная работа с данными в веб-приложении

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, sqlite, d3.js

подскажите как лучше реализовать следующее:

Имеется веб-приложение (сайт, который работает локально, то есть на самом пк открытием index.html), туда я хочу заносить некоторые данные (условно в инпуты или ещё как-то), обработать (нарисовать d3.js какие-нибудь связи или график), а затем сохранить их на том же пк в любом виде(главное чтобы можно было передать файл с данными отдельно) т.е localstorage, websql, куки) не подходит. А затем при новом открытии index.html выбрать какие данным интересуют, такой файл и открыть, чтобы данные подгрузились обратно в инпуты или ещё куда-то.

Какими инструментами можно воспользоваться?

Где-то читал, что indexedBD может сильно расширяться и экспортироваться и импортироваться.

Или же использовать node.js с excel или sqlite как-то локально без поднятия сервера?

Comment: можно хранить в mongodb atlas или firebase

Comment: это облачные, меня интересуют локальные

Comment: ну так и экспортируйте в файл

Answer (score 0):

Возможно  https://web.dev/browser-nativefs/ то что вы искали.
Вы можете хранить данные в файле в json(или каком то другом) формате и расшаривать эти файлы. Эта библиотека поддерживает ещё не широко используемые File System Access API или старый метод доступа к файлам через браузер.